# From inside one Docker container, how to connect to the port of another Docker container on the same Docker host?

Tags: docker, docker-network

Running the new Docker 20.10.1 on Ubuntu 20.04. This version includes the [support for host.docker.internal in dockerd on Linux](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/40007)

```
root@docker04:~# docker --version
Docker version 20.10.1, build 831ebea
```

I run a bunch of services in containers that use SSL certificates and I want to check the certificates for expiration using Telegraf (to later send to a Grafana dashboard).

All the services with web interfaces and Telegraf run on the same Docker host. All the services are in their own bridge network. I want to connect **from** Telegraf **to** Portainer on port 9000 (see below).

```
----------VM running docker (10.10.1.32)----------
|                                                |
|    --------------------                        |
|    | Gitea            |                        |     
|    | Ports: 3000:3000 |                        |
|    | Network: gitea   |                        |
|    --------------------                        |
|                                                |
|    ----------------------                      |
|    | Portainer          |                      |
|    | Ports: 9000:9000   |<--|                  |
|    | Network: portainer |   |                  |
|    ----------------------   |                  |
|                             |                  |
|    ---------------------    |                  |
|    | Telegraf          |    |                  |
|    | Network: telegraf |-->-                   |
|    |                   |                       |
|    ---------------------                       |
|                                                |
--------------------------------------------------
```

I thought with the new support for host.docker.internal, I would be able to connect from one container to another, but that doesn't see to be working. Ping works, but I can't connect to port 9000.

```
root@docker04:~# docker run -it --add-host host.docker.internal:host-gateway alpine /bin/sh
/ # ping host.docker.internal
PING host.docker.internal (172.17.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.17.0.1: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.102 ms
64 bytes from 172.17.0.1: seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.100 ms
^C
/ # telnet host.docker.internal 9000
telnet: can't connect to remote host (172.17.0.1): Operation timed out
```

The last command for telnet hangs and eventually disconnects. Am I missing something here? Will this only work with host networking? I'm obviously misunderstanding something about Docker networking here...

It also fails if I try to use the host's IP as well.

```
/ # telnet 10.10.1.32 9000
telnet: can't connect to remote host (10.10.1.32): Operation timed out
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to run on all container on same network or map two network on one container like on 1 container with network1, network2, why you are facing this issue because you are using different private bridge network for each container.